# .htaccess Redirect Subdomain to External URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

We need to run a few subdomains from our main site and we need to point these to external sites that deal with the admin required.

I simply need to redirect a subdomain to an external URL using .htaccess and also any advise about where to put it in the .htaccess file e.g. right at the top, as i know this effects certain rewrite rules.

I won't write what i think it should be as this just leads the answer down a specific route.

Cheers Guys,

Really appreciate it.

Dan

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you are redirecting a subdomain to another domain then there shouldn't be anything else in the .htaccess file other than this.

```
 # This will redirect a subdomain to another domain
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursubdomain\.yourdomain\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: This did not work, I have tried this exact method previously but for some reason it wont seem to take.

I am not sure why?? Any other ideas?

Comment: This works great, but I was wondering...do you know a way to do this without changing the URL? So the page redirects but still keeps `yoursubdomain.yourdomain.com` in the address bar.

Comment: @JLewkovich there is no way to do that. The idea of the address bar to is to tell people where they are. However You could iframe the other site.

Comment: Line 5-6 doesn't works. Are the first definitions affecting that. https://gist.github.com/santosh/134f7f3c36a6dd7f11f1

Comment: @JLewkovich, this is done in the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23027847/htaccess-specific-url-to-different-port). You'll simply have to tweak it a bit for the subdomain.

Answer (score 2):

I tried both options but didn't work until I remove the $ and [L,R]
this is the code that worked for me

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*) http://newdomain.com.ar/?param=data&uparam2=data
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code I used and it worked for me:

```
# BEGIN CUSTOM Redirects
# This will redirect a subdomain to another domain
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^pw\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.example.com [L,R
```