# .htaccess specific URL to different port

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want redirect some URLs to a different PORT. My .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)(\.)(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

I need to add a rule that redirects all requests with ^some-prefix/ at the beginning to port 8080, example:

1- URL

```
http://www.mysite.com/page1
```

will redirect to

```
http://www.mysite.com/page1/
```

BUT

2- URL

```
http://www.mysite.com/some-prefix/page2
```

will redirect to

```
http://www.mysite.com:8080/some-prefix/page2/
```

How can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do it this way

```
RewriteEngine on

# redirect to 8080 if current port is not 8080 and "some-prefix/" is matched
RewriteRule ^some-prefix/(.*[^/])/?$ http://www.mysite.com:8080/some-prefix/$1/ [R=301,L]

# redirect with trailing slash if not an existing file and no trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

EDIT: new code taking your comment into consideration

```
RewriteEngine on

# redirect to 8080 if "some-prefix/" is matched
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^8080$
RewriteRule ^some-prefix/(.*[^/])/?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:8080/some-prefix/$1/ [R=301,L]

# redirect with trailing slash if not an existing file and no trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. 1- There is a way I can only apply the rule of the Port isn't already 8080? 2- Can I avoid set the domain explicitly?

Comment: Sure. You can see my edited answer (i've added new code for that)

Comment: If you want to redirect /some-prefix too, add this below the first rule:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^8080$
RewriteRule ^some-prefix$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:8080/some-prefix [R=301,L]
```