# Pointing a domain to IP and port through htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want a certain subdomain to point to an IP address and port.

`sub.domain.com` needs to point to `123.123.123.123:111222`

I can point to the IP address with the webhosts built in DNS Manager, but it does not allow me to redirect to a port as well.

Answer (score 0):

[.htaccess specific URL to different port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23027847/htaccess-specific-url-to-different-port)

Above should have what you are seeking for in term of .htaccess integration since you tag it with .htaccess.

DNS Manage will not be able to redirect your subdomain to a particular port as DNS manager is used to point a subdomain to a particular ip address which you have already did.

port forwarding can be done in Iptable rules on a VPS/Dedicated Server or using a .htaccess in your web hosting folder which i assume you are on a shared hosting rather than a VPS/Dedicated Server.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Hm, yes I have seen this before, but it is not working. Actually I tried this first before asking this question. I'm not sure if I did anything wrong tough. If I do it this way, do I need to take off what I did with the DNS manager?

Comment: no , you don't have to. the DNS manager is necessary. It points your sub domain to the correct server. so when your browser type sub.domain.com,  your browser send request to your DNS manager and get the IP to go to your server location in layman term. Without DNS manager, your browser won't know where to go. So once the user has been redirected to your server, the next thing is, what do you want to do? and my suggestion was, redirect them to other port rather than the default port 80 :)

Comment: The problem is, the server its pointing to I have no way of making point to a different port. The server is just a dedicated minecraft server. No webhosting, no nothing of the sort, so I don't think I can get it to point to the port through that. Which means I have to do it from my webhost.

Comment: in that case, use iptables

     `sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080`

this will forward your port 80 to port 8080 on all internet connection through eth0

Comment: @BillyPope, this is exactly the issue I'm having as well, so I'm going attempt to remove the DNS mapping in the manager, to see if that allows the .htaccess to send the correct direction.