# How to redirect mysite.com:8080 to mysite.com htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect mysite.com:8080 to mysite.com with htaccess any ideas?

Comment: Read this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23027847/2536878

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with htaccess **at all**. This is possible with root users' permission or if the user running the apache server is in sudoers list. Port 80 is protected from rest of the users.

You can use `iptables` to forward requests from port 8080 to 80. That way, both `mysite.com:8080` and `mysite.com` will work. Another option would be to set the server to listen at port 80 as well. The latter can be done by adding:

```
Listen 80
```

in apache's configuration files.