# how to redirect all subdomains globally to parent domain

Tags: .htaccess

What do I place in my .htaccess file to redirect all pages related to a subdomain to it's parent domain.

So basically all pages related to

```
http://products.example.com redirects 

to 

http://example.com
```

I need ALL pages that are related to the subdomain to redirect to the root domain.

> Example:
>
> http://products.example.com/page1
>   http://products.example.com/anotherpage
>   http://products.example.com/somepagename etc..

All go to http://www.example.com

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989162/htaccess-redirect-subdomain-to-external-url

Comment: Neither of those solutions mentioned on that page work because all subdomains that have pages go to 404 pages.

For instance. http://products.example.com/page1 will go to a 404 page.

I'm looking to send all subdomains to the parent domain.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^products\.silvercross\.com$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.products\.silvercross\.com$
    RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.silvercross\.com\/" [R=301,L] `