# How to redirect AWS Lightsail subdomain to external URL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, .htaccess, subdomain

We recently moved over our WordPress installation to to AWS Lightsail, we've successfully moved our website and configured the DNS to point to the domain correctly.

I cannot figure out how to forward a subdomain to an external URL.

I've tried creating an s3 bucket, then back in to the Lightsail DNS to create an A record to point to this bucket -- but the created bucket does not show up.

If I try to create a CNAME record with the subdomain `social.mywebsite.com` and map it to an external url -- I get the error `must be a valid domain name`

I would try modifying the htaccess file to redirect the subdomain via Apache ([.htaccess Redirect Subdomain to External URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989162/htaccess-redirect-subdomain-to-external-url)) but I cannot figure out how to connect to my Lightsail server via FTP.

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: What are exactly trying to do open s3 bucket from a subdomain or what please be specific ?

Comment: We're trying to forward a subdomain (through Lightsail DNS) to an external URL -- the s3 bucket method was just something we found online to redirect a Lightsail subdomain to an external URL.

Comment: i could not find subdomain settings on lightsail dns console you can however ssh into your lightsail machine and use htaaccess for same purpose